# asp.net 4.7 web api not handling routing correctly when deployed

Tags: asp.net, url, iis, routes, service

There is a reason why we had to go with asp.net web api for the time being and not going to look into core at this time.

We deployed to our test server and we're getting a strange issue with the routing seemingly not working. When performing a request like http://localhost:8080/api/controller/id IIS is mapping the request to a physical resource like C:/mappedDirectory/api/controller/id that obviously is not present. It's like routing is completely non functional.

The routing works as expected when running from iis express in visual studio, but when deployed to a server it just doesn't seem to work at all. We currently are not using the url rewrite module, and from my understanding it's just not necessary to have it installed, but that's another option if it is useful to have installed.

Comment: Can you share configuration information for your site? or you can try using Fiddler to see what causes mapping the request to a physical resource is not present.